# Merge rows of data based on one column and put the duplicate values into new column

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I have some data, that looks something like this -

[image: Student information]

I need to group / merge the records based on student number / name and add their respective marks-subjects in new column, Something like below --

[image: Merge student info]

I am okay to accomplish this via Excel/Python/ Any programming language.

I tried merging the rows based on KEY value using consolidate option, but it didn't work out. Also tried iterating it using python, but wasn't fruitful. Any help here is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `Pandas` library (if you prefer to do it using `Python`). The following code should work for you.
It processes the `dataframe` that contains your student data, `groups` it by unique student attributes (Number, Name, Address), and rearranges it to have alternating Subject and Marks columns.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
# Sample data
data = {
    'Number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3],
    'Name': ['John', 'Kate', 'Angela', 'Ross', 'John', 'Kate', 'Mitchln', 'Kate', 'John', 'Angela'],
    'Address': ['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbb', 'cccccccc', 'ddddddd', 'aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbb', 'eeeeeee', 'bbbbbbb', 'aaaaaaa',
                'cccccccc'],
    'Subject': ['Maths', 'Maths', 'Maths', 'English', 'Science', 'Science', 'Maths', 'English', 'English', 'English'],
    'Marks': [55, 89, 77, 90, 67, 46, 54, 97, 88, 85]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
output_df = pd.DataFrame()
for name, group in df.groupby(['Number', 'Name', 'Address']):
    row = {'Number': name[0], 'Name': name[1], 'Address': name[2]}
    subject_marks = list(zip(group['Subject'], group['Marks']))
    for i, (subject, marks) in enumerate(subject_marks, start=1):
        row[f'Subject_{i}'] = subject
        row[f'Marks_{i}'] = marks
    output_df = pd.concat([output_df, pd.DataFrame([row])], ignore_index=True)
output_df = output_df.fillna('')
column_order = ['Number', 'Name', 'Address']
for i in range(1, df['Subject'].nunique() + 1):
    column_order.append(f'Subject_{i}')
    column_order.append(f'Marks_{i}')
output_df = output_df[column_order]
print(output_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a single cell Excel formula.
Assuming your non-header data starts in cell A2:

```
=LET(
    a, A2:E11,
    b, DROP(a, , -2),
    c, TAKE(a, , -2),
    d, TAKE(a, , 1),
    e, UNIQUE(d),
    calc, HSTACK(
        UNIQUE(b),
        DROP(
            REDUCE(
                "",
                SEQUENCE(ROWS(e)),
                LAMBDA(i,v, VSTACK(i, TOROW(FILTER(c, INDEX(e, v, ) = d))))
            ),
            1
        )
    ),
    IFERROR(calc,"")
)
```

[image: Picture Reference]